# Deploying contracts on geth returns Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, truffle

I'm using `truffle` (which uses `pudding`) to deploy contracts to my `testrpc`.

No I'm running a `geth` instance locally with:

> geth --mine -rpccorsdomain "*" --ipcapi "admin,eth,miner" --rpcapi
>   "eth,web3" --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --minerthreads 1 --unlock "0xXXXXXXXXetc.." console

Now when I try to deploy my contracts, I get:

`Invalid JSON RPC response: "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545 at..."`

What am I missing here? How does truffle/pudding identify itself to the node, when it deploys? (i.e. `truffle deploy`) I can't see anything to configure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the default port is not 8545, and had to add these options:

`--rpc --rpcport 8545`

Comment: Actually, the default port is 8545, but you need to use the `--rpc` flag to enable RPC connections

Answer (score 1):

Contract compilation is described in detail [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions#compiling-a-contract); an example may look like:

```
./geth --datadir ~/eth/ --loglevel 6 --logtostderr=true --rpc --rpcport 8100 --rpccorsdomain '*' --mine console  2>> ~/eth/eth.log
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_compileSolidity","params":["contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"],"id":1}' http://127.0.0.1:8100
```

(make sure you are connecting to the right ports).

Contract deployment is shown [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions#creating-and-deploying-a-contract):

```
source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
// compile with solc
contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
// create contract object
var MyContract = eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition)
// extracts info from contract, save the json serialisation in the given file, 
contenthash = admin.saveInfo(contract.info, "~/dapps/shared/contracts/test/info.json")
// send off the contract to the blockchain
MyContract.new({from: primaryAccount, data: contract.code}, function(error, contract){
  if(!error && contract.address) {
    // calculates the content hash and registers it with the code hash in `HashReg`
    // it uses address to send the transaction. 
    // returns the content hash that we use to register a url
    admin.register(primaryAccount, contract.address, contenthash)
    // here you deploy ~/dapps/shared/contracts/test/info.json to a url
    admin.registerUrl(primaryAccount, hash, url)
  }
});
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Done, edited the answer.

Comment: The question is more about how truffle identifies itself to a node, i.e. which account is it using to deploy (when doing `truffle deploy`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all,you need to add a rpc port in your geth as : `geth --rpc --rpcport "portnumber"`. 
Then in your truffle project folder there will a file named *truffle.js*.You need to update the rpc section as section

```
rpc: {
   host: "localhost",
   port: portnumber
 }
```

Thus it will be connected to tehy node running locally on your system.Now you just need to run the command `truffle deploy` and your contracts will be deployed on your private blockchain. Error is appearing because of the default value set in truffle.js file which is trying to connect a local node running on the port 8545. I hope it will resolve your issue.