# Deploying contracts on geth returns {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, testrpc

I'm trying to connect geth with truffle to deploy my contracts to my testrpc. When I run truffle deploy it's running but when I do http://localhost:8545/ it's throwing

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

as JSON is invalid. My geth is working properly and I'm using same ports in geth and truffle. When I do

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x822a9cba371309c14e2235057fc561156212cd94", "860"],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

it throws

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"\u003cnil\u003e"}
```

which I am unable to understand. Where am I going wrong?
And is pudding necessary to connect geth and truffle?

I tried this link but no luck
[Deploying contracts on geth returns Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/deploying-contracts-on-geth)

Comment: there were some answers.. where did it go?

Comment: The answers were deleted as the answer they were attached to contained a malicious scam site link. Could you replicate the results from http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6888/getting-contract-balance-over-json-rpc ? Your eth_getBalance RPC request contains "860" as the block number. Does "latest" in the same field make any difference to the results you are returned?

Comment: latest didnt make any difference , but it was returning the correct answer.. i could deploy the test contracts properly.. my doubt is how to proceed further.. http://localhost:8545/ is still giving same 32600 error..